# adding 「化」as a suffix can create サ変名詞, right？What is the technical term for this?

Tags: words, kanji

"Personification" might be the term for adding 「人」or「者」as a suffix to a noun.

I am pretty sure that 「化」can also function as a suffix to a noun. My perception is that adding 「化」as a suffix "injects action", and enables the newly formed noun to feel like gerunds and infinitives (which insert action into sentences via nouns), as well as function as a サ変名詞：
「兵器」= "weapon"; 「兵器化する」= "to weaponize";
「可視」= "visibility"; 「可視化する」= "to visualize";
「コモディティー」= "commodity"; 「コモディティー化する」= "to commoditize";
*I am sure that there are many examples. They would be used in newspapers to make articles as short as possible?*

(1) But, does the construct of "injecting action" with a「化」suffix really exist？
(2) What are some websites that explain this?
(3) Is there a short phrase in English, or Japanese, that is used to identify this construct?

Comment: I understand "personification" to mean something like [anthropomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism), and not to be anything related to adding suffices. (But I'm no linguist...)

Comment: personification/anthropomorphism is 擬人化, for the record

Comment: Here's a website that explains this. Well... a dictionary entry, really http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%8C%96&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02707000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verbal morpheme [化【か】](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%8C%96&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02707000) in Japanese acts as a derivational suffix.  Since it's a verbal morpheme (as in Chinese), it forms verbal nouns from regular nouns.  These verbal nouns can be used in periphrastic constructions with する (see [Japanese "Verbal Noun and *suru*" Constructions](http://www.billposer.org/Papers/japper.pdf) by Bill Poser).

It corresponds fairly closely to *-ization* or *-ification*.  It adds the meaning *-ize, -(i)fy* (intransitively: "to become", transitively: "to cause to become"), but the resulting compound is still a syntactically a noun.  Placing it in a periphrastic construction with する allows it to be used as a verb:

```
 武器　　　　　　　　weapon
 武器化　　　　　　　weaponization
 武器化する　　　　　weaponize
```

In particular, this suffix can be attached to *adjectival nouns* (called 形容動詞の語幹 in traditional grammar):

```
 グローバル　　　　　global
 グローバル化　　　　globalization
 グローバル化する　　globalize
```

But as [jovanni points out](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13138/13147?noredirect=1#comment28163_13147), the resulting words don't work quite the same way; the result of グローバル化する is not a グローバル, but a thing which is global.

Much like English *-ize* and *-(i)fy* affixation, Japanese 化 affixation is a productive process, so you can add it to nouns whenever you feel it makes sense to do so:

```
 階層　　　　　　　　stratum
 階層化　　　　　　　stratification
 階層化する　　　　　stratify
 アイコン　　　　　　icon
 アイコン化　　　　　iconization
 アイコン化する　　　iconize
```

Of course, the stranger it is semantically, [the sillier the result is](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1285146442):

```
 ハンバーガー　　　　hamburger
 ハンバーガー化　　　hamburgerization
 ハンバーガー化する　hamburgerize
```

But I think that as long as a noun can be interpreted as something other than a verbal noun, 化 can attach to it.  It seems to be very productive!

Comment: Just to add, -化 can also add the intransitive meaning “to become” as in ビジネスがグローバル化する, just like many other nouns which can be turned into a verb by adding する.

Comment: Is グローバル a _noun_ in this case? I think グローバル is an adjective here.
The resulting thing by グローバル化 is not a グローバル , but somrthing which has the property グローバル.